# pandas to_csv index format

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame where row index is date. I want to call `to_csv` where I can specify row index format as `%Y%m%d`, it doesn't seem to be working for me since the row index output is in the format of `%Y-%m-%d`, anyway to force this method to output desired row index?

I can iterate rows to output as my desired format but it is just too slow for me.
Here is my code for out putting to csv file.

```
df.to_csv(fn, na_rep='nan', header=False, index=True, date_format="%Y%m%d")
```

The out put looks like:

```
2000-01-05,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,25.5,25.4,25.4,25.36,0.0
```

I want to look like:

```
20000105,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,25.5,25.4,25.4,25.36,0.0
```

Comment: Are you sure that the index is a date, and not a string?  What does `df.index.dtype` give?

Comment: Have you tested to see what strftime() would do to the date? In the 'old' days one would have to convert to a string before output. If your installation has a problem (and it is not a typo in the code), then that could allow a work around. I am assuming that you have made sure that your data for output is indeed in date format and there is no typo in the original code. I have seen situations in which the type is string rather than date.

Comment: It is datetime format: `print df.index.dtype` output `datetime64[ns]`, `df.index[0].strftime("%Y%m%d")` prints `'20000105'`

Comment: This works for me in today's version of pandas ('0.13.1-648-gad1f47d'): `print towrite.to_csv(date_format='%Y%m%d')` `time,jdate,orbit,sundist
20101220,2455550.916667521,6867.0,0.98631
20101220,2455550.916669002,6867.0,0.98631
20101220,2455550.916670484,6867.0,0.98631
20101220,2455550.916671965,6867.0,0.98631
20101220,2455550.916673446,6867.0,0.98631`